nuitka cant find numba pyd
Ive got some AOT .pyd files that i compiled in Numba (needed faster processing) and im now trying to include those Numba .pyd files in a Nuitka standalone onefile exe.  I am not using yml config files yet.
The nuitka exe builds fine, but when running, it finds and imports one of my .pyd files just fine in the same directory as the .py file that im building.  It has trouble with a second .pyd in ..\directory2 .
For other troublesome py files in the same ..\directory2, ive been able to instruct Nuitka to find them by using --include-plugin-files=path to directory2\my_file.py and it works like a charm.
However, the same --include-plugin-files=path to directory2\my_numba_file.pyd does not work on the pyd.
It gets to the point of "nuitka running depends.exe for path to directory2\my_numba_file.pyd, detecting dlls used...
assert finding == "absolute", standalone_entry_point.module_name
and then it quits.
Oddly enough, if i copy the troublesome .pyd file into the same directory as the first .pyd, everything builds and runs correctly.
Code works perfectly outside of Nuitka too.
Ive tried using --include-package and --include-module  but it comes back with "cant find the package that you asked to locate"
Is there a trick to including .pyd files from separate directories?
thanks!!
